# Unable to improve tag wiki excerpts (I get a blank box)

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki-excerpt, improve-edit

I was reviewing suggested edits on Stack Overflow and saw two tag wiki excerpts that I wanted to improve: [source-separation](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1380100), [convex-hull](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1380303).

When I clicked “Improve”, I reached the usual improve UI. However the box that should have contained the text of the suggestion was blank. At the time I clicked “Improve”, the suggestions were still shown as pending. They have since then been approved. I'm not completely sure I did click the button before the final approval vote, it may have been a close call. The edit was still shown as pending when I reloaded the page.

I should either have seen a message “this edit has already been approved”, or have had an editor page with a box containing the text of the suggestion. Getting an empty box might have made sense if the initial excerpt suggestion had been rejected (but it still would have been poor UI), but these suggestions were approved.

Improving Q/A and tag wiki bodies works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed. When we improved the UI for inline-editing tag wiki excerpts, we introduced a bug in which the textarea was pre-populated with the *original* tag wiki excerpt rather than the suggested version.