# Tag wiki excerpt appears empty when suggested edit is improved

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki-excerpt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to improve tag wiki excerpts (I get a blank box)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164753/unable-to-improve-tag-wiki-excerpts-i-get-a-blank-box)

I'd like to improve [this suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/76494)…

[image]

But when I click *Improve*, the tag wiki shows up as empty:

[image]

What gives? Where's the edit?